# Why load-foreign-library does not work in ECL?

Tags: common-lisp, ffi, ecl

I compiled ECL 16.1.3 on Windows and I want to load the shared library but FFI does not work.

At first I used CFFI and then got the error 'unable to load'. Then I found the ECL limitation (On platforms where ECL’s dynamic FFI is not supported (ie. when :dffi is not present in *features*), cffi:load-foreign-library does not work and you must use ECL’s own ffi:load-foreign-library with a constant string argument) in the CFFI manual.

I do not have `:dffi` so I decided to use `ffi:load-foreign-library` instead of `cffi:load-foreign-library`but `ffi:load-foreign-library` also does not work.

```
(ffi:load-foreign-library "С:/.../libglib-2.0-0.dll")
nil
```

So I have two questions:
1) How to make `ffi:load-foreign-library` work?
2) How to compile ECL with `:dffi` support?